# Glassfish Jdbc-connectioPool Issue

Tags: mysql, glassfish

Hi I am getting the following exception frequently in glassfish can any one help me on this.
    The log message is null.

```
   The log message is null.
   java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Wrong XAState: 0
at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:115)
at com.sify.beaserv.bean.PollBoxBean.getNode(PollBoxBean.java:754)
at com.sify.beaserv.bean.PollBoxBean.buildAlarm(PollBoxBean.java:317)
at com.sify.beaserv.bean.PollBoxBean.processNode(PollBoxBean.java:652)
at com.sify.beaserv.bean.PollBoxBean.onMessage(PollBoxBean.java:60)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor185.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1011)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:175)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:2929)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4020)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.deliverMessage(MessageBeanContainer.java:1111)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:74)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:179)
at $Proxy76.onMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:258)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:76)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
```

Comment: http://www.java.net/node/684862 and http://www.java.net/node/684788

Answer (score 0):

The exception message `Wrong XAState: 0` suggests that you're trying to use an XA driver, which is correct for two-phase commit.  Is that true?  Do you know which JDBC driver and which database vendor you're using?  Do you get this message right at start up, or is it after you've been running successfully for a while?